# Generating JSON in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, json

I need to generate JSON output as below:

```
[{
    "Service": "service1-name",
    "AWS Account": "service1-dev",
    "AD Accounts": {
        "APP-Service1-Admin": ["a", "b"],
        "APP-Service1-View": ["c", "d"]
    }
}
]
```

I'm trying this shell script, but I can't insert inner info

```
#!/bin/bash
innerAD=$(jq -n --arg aaaa aaaa \
              --arg xxxx "xxxx" \
              '$ARGS.named'
)
inner=$(jq -n --argjson "APP-Service1-Admin" "[$innerAD]" \
              '$ARGS.named'
)
final=$(jq -n --arg Service "service1-name" \
              --arg "AWS Account" "service1-dev" \
              --argjson "AD Accounts" "[$inner]" \
              '$ARGS.named'
)
echo "$final"
```

Comment: what is `$ARGS.named` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/kislyuk/yq would be an option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One suggestion is to use `--args` with `jq` to create the two arrays and then collect these in the correct location in the main document. Note that `--args` is required to be the last option on the command line and that *all* the remaining command line arguments will become elements of the `$ARGS.positional` array.

```bash
{
    jq -n --arg key APP-Service1-Admin '{($key): $ARGS.positional}' --args a b
    jq -n --arg key APP-Service1-View  '{($key): $ARGS.positional}' --args c d
} |
jq -s --arg key 'AD Accounts' '{($key): add}' |
jq --arg Service service1-name --arg 'AWS account' service1-dev '$ARGS.named + .'
```

The first two `jq` invocations create a set of two JSON objects:

```json
{
  "APP-Service1-Admin": [
    "a",
    "b"
  ]
}
{
  "APP-Service1-View": [
    "c",
    "d"
  ]
}
```

The third `jq` invocation uses `-s` to read that set into an array, which becomes a merged object when passed through `add`.  The merged object is assigned to our top-level key:

```json
{
  "AD Accounts": {
    "APP-Service1-Admin": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    "APP-Service1-View": [
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  }
}
```

The last `jq` adds the remaining top-level keys and their values to the object:

```json
{
  "Service": "service1-name",
  "AWS account": "service1-dev",
  "AD Accounts": {
    "APP-Service1-Admin": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    "APP-Service1-View": [
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

With `jo`:

```bash
jo -d . \
    Service=service1-name \
    'AWS account'=service1-dev  \
    'AD Accounts.APP-Service1-Admin'="$(jo -a a b)" \
    'AD Accounts.APP-Service1-View'="$(jo -a c d)"
```

The "internal" object is created using `.`-notation (enabled with `-d .`), and a couple of command substitutions for creating the arrays.

Or you can drop the `-d .` and use a form of array notation:

```bash
jo  Service=service1-name \
    'AWS account'=service1-dev \
    'AD Account[APP-Service1-Admin]'="$(jo -a a b)" \
    'AD Account[APP-Service1-View]'="$(jo -a c d)"
```

Comment: Can I pass a variable on ```jo -a``` command?
I have a variable like: 
```MyVAR="'Surname1, Name1 (Role1)' 'Surname2, Name2 (Role2)'"```

Comment: @MarcoFerrara If you have an array, like `myvar=('Surname1, Name1 (Role1)' 'Surname2, Name2 (Role2)')`, then you would pass that to `jo -a` like so: `jo -a "${myvar[@]}"`.  If your variable is a single string, as you show, including literal single quotes etc., then you will want to preprocess that with some tool that is able to isolate the elements correctly and assign them to an array

Answer (score 4):

I often use heredocs when creating complicated json objects in bash:

```
service=$(thing-what-gets-service)
account=$(thing-what-gets-account)
admin=$(jo -a $(thing-what-gets-admin))
view=$(jo -a $(thing-what-gets-view))

read -rd '' json <<EOF
[
    {
        "Service": "$service",
        "AWS Account": "$account",
        "AD Accounts": {
            "APP-Service1-Admin": $admin,
            "APP-Service1-View": $view
        }
    }
]
EOF
```

This uses `jo` to create the arrays as it's a pretty simple way to do it but it could be done differently if needed.

Comment: Yes.  For this use case, a heredoc can be thought of as a special kind of quoting.   It's pretty good for SQL commands, too.  It's not perfect, but avoids the need to create double- and triple-backslashes to protect characters like `"` and `'` (double-quote and single-quote).

Comment: @SottoVoce Many database command line tools allows you to use parametrised SQL queries, e.g. `psql --variable passwd='mypassword' <<<"ALTER USER me WITH PASSWORD :'passwd'"` (using here-string for brevity). This takes care of quoting. jesse_b's solution here is ok _only_ because we know that `$admin` and `$view` already are correctly encoded JSON documents, but I'm uneasy about `$service` and `$account` (he could have encoded them easily with `jo` too).

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm sure there are some gotchas to doing it this way but they would most likely have to be intentionally malicious as the common issues with whitespace and even new lines wouldn't cause an issue.  I could have done it all with jo but the only way I know how would be a far less readable combination of unmanageable nested command substitutions.

Comment: Actually I guess it would choke on newlines, but not whitespace.

Comment: String concatenation is absolutely the wrong way to create JSON. **But** every time I have to use `jq` I end up spending 4 hours going through documentation to figure out how to use it, so +1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

Another `jo` answer:

```bash
# 2 shell arrays
admins=("a" "b")
views=("c" "d")

accounts=$(jo "${admins[@]/#/APP_Service1-Admin[]=}" "${views[@]/#/APP_Service1-View[]=}")

final=$(jo "Service=service1-name" "AWS Account=service1-dev" "AD Accounts=$accounts")

echo "$final" | jq .
```

```json
{
  "Service": "service1-name",
  "AWS Account": "service1-dev",
  "AD Accounts": {
    "APP_Service1-Admin": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    "APP_Service1-View": [
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the tricky bit: `"${admins[@]/#/APP_Service1-Admin[]=}"`

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' "${admins[@]/#/APP_Service1-Admin[]=}"
APP_Service1-Admin[]=a
APP_Service1-Admin[]=b
```

That lets you build up a list from a shell array.

Answer (score 2):

[xo(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xo&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%20Ports%2013.1) is a great utility for generating JSON on the command line. It comes from the [libxo](https://github.com/Juniper/libxo) project developed by Juniper. Conveniently, it has been preinstalled on [FreeBSD since 11.0-RELEASE](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.0R/relnotes/) and can output JSON and other formats like XML. This is the mechanism used by many FreeBSD administration tools (e.g., [ps(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)) to support machine-friendly output formats.

Here are output examples from the manual page.

```
$ xo --style text "The {k:name} weighs {:weight/%d} pounds.\n" fish 6
The fish weighs 6 pounds.

$ xo --style xml "The {k:name} weighs {:weight/%d} pounds.\n" fish 6
<name>fish</name>
<weight>6</weight>

$ xo --style json "The {k:name} weighs {:weight/%d} pounds.\n" fish 6
"name": "fish",
"weight": 6
"name": "fish",

$ xo --style html "The {k:name} weighs {:weight/%d} pounds.\n" fish 6
<div class="line">
     <div class="text">The </div>
     <div class="data" data-tag="name">fish</div>
     <div class="text"> weighs </div>
     <div class="data" data-tag="weight">6</div>
     <div class="text"> pounds.</div>
</div>
```